# How to retrieve userInfo with oidc-client-ts in a React/TS project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, openid-connect

Bonjour,

I'm working on a React/TS project that needs to use the oidc-client-ts library to manage user authentication.
For the moment, I have a service that contains the "oidcSettings" and calls the methods available in the oidc-client-ts library. This service is called by a contextProvider.

Here is the source code of some components:

- **main.tsx** :

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@emotion/react'
import { CssBaseline } from '@mui/material'
import React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOMClient from 'react-dom/client'
import theme from './theme'
import { AuthProvider } from './hooks/AuthProvider'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import Routes from './Routes'

ReactDOMClient.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
).render(
  <AuthProvider>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <React.StrictMode>
          <Routes />
        </React.StrictMode>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </AuthProvider>
)
```

- **Routes.tsx** :

```
import { Route, Routes as RouterRoutes } from 'react-router-dom'
import PublicPage from './components/PublicPage'
import ProtectedPage from './components/ProtectedPage'


const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <RouterRoutes>
      <Route path="/" element={<PublicPage />} /> // **contains a LoginButton**
      <Route path="/oidcCallback" element={<ProtectedPage />} />
    </RouterRoutes>
  )
}

export default Routes
```

- **useAuth.tsx** :

```
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { AuthContext } from './AuthProvider'

const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext)
}

export default useAuth
```

- **AuthService.ts** :

```
import { User, UserManager, WebStorageStateStore } from 'oidc-client-ts'
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react'

export interface AuthServiceProps {
  getUser(): Promise<User | null>
  login(): Promise<void>
  logout(): Promise<void>
  renewToken(): Promise<User | null>
  signinCallback(): Promise<User>
}

const useAuthService = (): AuthServiceProps => {
  const oidcSettings = {
    authority: 'https://...',
    client_id: 'myClientId',
    client_secret: 'mySecret',
    redirect_uri: 'http://...',
    response_type: 'code',
    scope: 'otherScope profile openid email',
    loadUserInfo: true,
    userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage }),
    metadata: {
      authorization_endpoint:
        'https://...',
      issuer: 'https://...',
      token_endpoint: 'https://...',
      userinfo_endpoint: 'https://...',
    },
  }

  const userManager = new UserManager(oidcSettings)

  const getUser = (): Promise<User | null> => {
    return userManager.getUser()
  }

  const login = (): Promise<void> => {
    return userManager.signinRedirect()
  }

  const logout = (): Promise<void> => {
    return userManager.signoutRedirect()
  }

  const renewToken = (): Promise<User | null> => {
    return userManager.signinSilent()
  }

  const signinCallback = (): Promise<User> => {
    return userManager.signinRedirectCallback()
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser().then(user => {
      console.log('userInfo via AuthService.getUSer() : ', user) // null
    })
  }, [])

  return {
    getUser,
    login,
    logout,
    renewToken,
    signinCallback,
  }
}

export default useAuthService
```

- **AuthProvider.tsx** :

```
import {
  ReactElement,
  createContext,
  useEffect,
  useMemo,
  useState,
} from 'react'
import useAuthService from '../AuthService'
import { User } from 'oidc-client-ts'

interface AuthContextProps {
  userFromContext: User | null
  getUserFromContext: () => void
  loginFromContext: () => void
  logoutFromContext: () => void
  renewTokenFromContext: () => void
  signinCallbackFromContext: () => void
}

interface AuthProviderProps {
  children: ReactElement
}

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextProps>({
  userFromContext: null,
  getUserFromContext: () => {},
  loginFromContext: () => {},
  logoutFromContext: () => {},
  renewTokenFromContext: () => {},
  signinCallbackFromContext: () => {},
})

const AuthProvider = ({ children }: AuthProviderProps) => {
  const [userFromContext, setUserFromContext] = useState<User | null>(null)
  const { getUser, login, logout, renewToken, signinCallback } =
    useAuthService()

  const getUserFromContext = (): Promise<User | null> => {
    return getUser()
  }

  const loginFromContext = (): Promise<void> => {
    return login()
  }

  const logoutFromContext = (): Promise<void> => {
    return logout()
  }

  const renewTokenFromContext = (): Promise<User | null> => {
    return renewToken()
  }

  const signinCallbackFromContext = (): Promise<User> => {
    return signinCallback()
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserFromContext().then(user => {
      setUserFromContext(user)
      console.log('userFromContext via AuthProvider : ', userFromContext) // null
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        userFromContext,
        getUserFromContext,
        loginFromContext,
        logoutFromContext,
        renewTokenFromContext,
        signinCallbackFromContext,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}

export { AuthContext, AuthProvider }
```

- **LoginButton.tsx** :

```
import useAuth from '../hooks/useAuth'

const Login = () => {
  const { loginFromContext } = useAuth()

  const handleClick = () => {
    loginFromContext()
  }

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Login</button>
}

export default Login
```

As a user, I manage to complete the authentication process but the console.log() that I added in the source code, display `null`.

Does anyone have an idea how I can get the userInfo (uid, access_token, email...), please? I'm new to React and I think I got confused with context management, but I don't see where.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**PS. The oidcSettings have been checked with a colleague and tested via Postman: everything is ok on that side.**

- I tried to modify my code several times
- Search on Internet (try with examples...)
- ...

Answer (score 1):

I would first add some `console.log` statements in other places. First ensure that `signInRedirectCallback` is actually being called, and that you can call `getUser()` afterwards and get an access token. After that, it is just React stuff to pass context around. From what I can see you are doing that correctly.

The usual approach in OAuth secured SPAs is to check for and handle OAuth login responses when the page loads, by checking for a state query parameter:

```
https://www.myapp.com?code=xxx&state=yyy
```

If OAuth response parameters are detected then call signInRedirectCallback. My [demo app](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts#L163) provides some example code, using the original oidc client library that your one is based on.

I would also recommend handling error responses as part of this, so that if there is ever an incorrect configuration or something, your app handles it gracefully.

Comment: Hello Gary,

thank you for your answer and the sample code. I'll take a look at it all!

Guillaume.